# Django-tenants creates user in public schema only

Tags: python, django

I am currently setting up Django Tenants (https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with the Saleor Web Framework (https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-platform).

I've managed to get the Saleor GraphQL endpoints up and running for two different sites. However, my users have to be created using the public schema or the login process does not work.

For instance if run `./manage.py create_tenant --domain-domain=newtenant.net --schema_name=new_tenant --email=new@gmail.com` this doesn't work. But running `./manage.py create_tenant --domain-domain=newtenant.net --schema_name=public --email=new@gmail.com` works.

The problem with creating in the public schema is that the created user will have access to all of the tenants.

Extract from my settings.py

```
SHARED_APPS = [
    "django_tenants",
    "saleor.clients",

    # Django modules
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.postgres",
    "storages",
    
    # Local apps
    "saleor.plugins",
    "saleor.account",
    "saleor.discount",
    "saleor.giftcard",
    "saleor.product",
    "saleor.checkout",
    "saleor.core",
    "saleor.graphql",
    "saleor.menu",
    "saleor.order",
    "saleor.seo",
    "saleor.shipping",
    "saleor.search",
    "saleor.site",

]

TENANT_APPS = (
    # The following Django contrib apps must be in TENANT_APPS
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.postgres",
    "storages",
    # Django modules
    
    # Local apps
    "saleor.plugins",
    "saleor.account",
    "saleor.discount",
    "saleor.giftcard",
    "saleor.product",
    "saleor.checkout",
    "saleor.core",
    "saleor.graphql",
    "saleor.menu",
    "saleor.order",
    "saleor.seo",
    "saleor.shipping",
    "saleor.search",
    "saleor.site",
    "saleor.data_feeds",
    "saleor.page",
    "saleor.payment",
    "saleor.warehouse",
    "saleor.webhook",
    "saleor.wishlist",
    "saleor.app",

    # External apps
    "versatileimagefield",
    "django_measurement",
    "django_prices",
    "django_prices_openexchangerates",
    "django_prices_vatlayer",
    "graphene_django",
    "mptt",
    "django_countries",
    "django_filters",
    "phonenumber_field",
)

INSTALLED_APPS = list(SHARED_APPS) + [app for app in TENANT_APPS if app not in SHARED_APPS]

TENANT_MODEL = "clients.Client" # app.Model

TENANT_DOMAIN_MODEL = "clients.Domain"  # app.Model
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Resolved it, turns out I was missing the middleware line: 'django_tenants.middleware.main.TenantMainMiddleware',

Comment: I'm trying to add multi-tenant to a Saleor app and I would love to know how you managed to make it working since the beginning. Could you provide some guidance on that?

Comment: please share how did u do it ?

Comment: Hi, do you want to know how I integrated Django tenants with Saleor?

Comment: Hi, do you have tutorial or article on how I can integrate django-tenants with Saleor? Thank you